# function visibility with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why when i am using `$('.clockpicker').clockpicker();` with timeout it raising error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).clockpicker is not a function`. why?

```
<script>
function loadClockPicker() {
    $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
}
function MyViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    setTimeout(loadClockPicker, 1);
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel);
```

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th>Time</th><th>Stool</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-align="top" data-autoclose="true">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="13:14">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Have you checked that necessary javascript files for ClockPicker plugin is rendered correctly ?

Comment: call the above functions in `document.ready`

Comment: Are you trying to run this script BEFORE jQuery has been loaded? If so, that's an issue.

Comment: You should include jquery before clockpicker.